# role's run_list is been overrided by env_run_lists

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I can't seem to understand why i get a different run result what i run chef, in different environments.
I have for the following setup:

a node.json file

```
{"run_list:" ["role[webfront]"]}
```

a webfront.json role:

```
{
    "name": "webfront",
    "chef_type": "role",
    "json_class": "Chef::Role",
    "description": "The base role for systems that serve HTTP traffic",

    "default_attributes": {},

    "override_attributes": {},

    "run_list": [
            "recipe[apt]",
            "recipe[java]",
            "role[apache-server]",
            "role[node-server]"
    ],

    "env_run_lists" : {
            "sandbox" : [
                    "role[redis-server]"
            ],
            "dev": [
                    "role[redis-server]"
            ]
    }
```

}

If i run:

```
sudo chef-solo -c solo.rb -j node.json -E sandbox
```

I get a different result then if i run it without no env at all:

```
sudo chef-solo -c solo.rb -j node.json
```

When i include the "sandbox" environment, only the env_run_lists recipes are included in the chef run

Why is that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that is how the feature works. If you are presuming the the environment-specific run list gets appended instead of replacing the default that would substantially limit the feature since you wouldn't be able to remove things from the default or change order.

Comment: It'd be helpful if the Chef documentation clearly stated env_run_lists setting completely overrides run_lists.